# Image upload validation without using @Assert

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to make image upload compulsory. I've tried it on a Collection Type by `@Assert\Valid` which was generating an error `Image is missing!` on the top of the form i.e. ***error bubbling*** then I removed `error bubbling` by setting it `false`. After removing ***error bubbling*** I'm unable to populate image missing error. How can I map the error to its form element i.e. `images`.

Please help & provide me possible solutions for this problem by using Symfony or jQuery. And also suggest the which one is best & why.

**Entity: XYZBundle\Entity\Abc.php**

```
     Class Abc
     {
         .....

         /**
         * @JMS\Groups({"details"})
         * @JMS\Expose
         *
         *@Assert\Valid
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        private $images;

        .....
```

**FormType: XYZBundle\Entity\AbcType.php**

```
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
           .....

            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => MediaType::class,
                    'label' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'error_bubbling' => false,

                ))

           .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following code into **AbcController** I'm able to show the error now. And I've now removed the `@Assert\Valid` from the Entity (XYZBundle\Entity\Abc.php).

**Controller: AbcController.php**

```
 $images = $form['images']->getData();
            $imageExist=false;
            foreach ($images as $image){
                if(!empty($image->getFilename())){
                    $imageExist=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!$imageExist){
                $form['images']->addError(new FormError("Please upload at least one image."));
            }
```

The only thing that is remaining is to map the error just after its form element.